# How can I get a Visualforce page to save into files on the opportunity page using an extension controller?

Tags: apex, visualforce, salesforce-lightning

I am new to Salesforce and this is the first time I've ever had to open the developer console, so bear with me, the code may be rough and I appreciate any help. I have a controller and visualforce page that work to compile products from the products list on the opportunity page, create a new (non-repeating) quote number, and compile all this on to a PDF with the company logo and in the desired format; this is all called from the click of a button on the opportunity page. I want a button on the visualforce page to then, after the PDF is made and shown, save the PDF into files.

**Visualforce page works as desired in creating my PDF**

```
<apex:page controller="QuoteOppProductCtrl" extensions="QuotePDFSaveExt" applyHtmlTag="false" showHeader="false" renderAs="PDF" action="{!generateAndStoreQuoteNumber}">  
----------------the body of the content of the PDF is here ------------
</apex:page>
```

**Main custom controller works as desired**

```
public with sharing class QuoteOppProductCtrl {
    public Date Today { get { return Date.today(); } }
    public Opportunity opportunity { get; set; }
    public String shipToAccountName { get; set; }
    public String prosthetistName { get; set; }
    public String fittingProsthetistId { get; set; }
    public String prosthetistEmail { get; set; }
    public Decimal subtotal { get; set; }
    public Decimal quoteTotal { get; set; }
    public String quoteNumber { get; set; } // To store the generated quote number
--------- body of controller ---------
```

**Controller Extension: UPDATED**
Error is stating that there is a null reference for QuotePDFSaveExt(ApexPages.StandardController ctrl)

```
public with sharing class QuotePDFSaveExt{
    String oppId{get;set;}
    public QuotePDFSaveExt(ApexPages.StandardController ctrl) {
        oppId = ctrl.getId();
    }
        
    public PageReference savePDF() {
      // Generate the PDF here
       PageReference pdfPage = Page.QuoteOppProductVfp;
      // recordId = opp.Id;
       pdfPage.getParameters().put('Id', oppId);
       pdfPage.setRedirect(true);
        
       PageReference ret;

        try {
      Blob pdfBlob = Test.isRunningTest()
        ? Blob.valueOf('Test PDF Content')
        : pdfPage.getContentAsPDF();

      ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion(
        Title = 'Quote ' + oppId,
        PathOnClient = 'Quote ' + oppId + '.pdf',
        VersionData = pdfBlob,
        FirstPublishLocationId = oppId
      );
      insert cv;
      ret = new ApexPages.StandardController([SELECT Id FROM ContentDocument WHERE LatestPublishedVersionId = :cv.Id]).view();
        } 
        catch (exception e) {
      ApexPages.addMessages(e);
        }
    return ret;

    }
}
```

**Added VFP to save PDF**

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="QuotePDFSaveExt">
    <apex:pageMessages />
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="preview and save">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!savePDF}" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:iframe src="{!URLFOR($Page.QuoteOppProductVfp, null, [id=Opportunity.Id])}" scrolling="true" />
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: You want it to be same page that renders as pdf/html depending on conditions? Doable but might be cleaner to split that into "form" page and "pretty pdf" page. And then onclick controller of 1 calls 2nd, pulls the content and saves?

Comment: I attempted renderAs = HTML  so I could try to have a separate "Save PDF" button - I think having the ability to double check the PDF before saving it would be ideal. If one button from the opportunity page can call both actions, then I can work with that, but I haven't figured out how I can do that.

Comment: It is possible to pull it off with 1 page, 1 controller and some clever use of `rerender` tags but if you're learning I suggest separating them. Have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the VFP and the controller worked in creating the PDF I needed as an output, these remained unchanged from my question. I took the advice of creating a separate controller to create a "save pdf" method, and a separate Visualforce page to have a "Save" button. The button from the opportunity page calls the new Visualforce page.

**The additional controller**

```
public class QuotePDFSaveExt {
public ID oppId { get; set; }
public Opportunity opportunity {get;set;}

public QuotePDFSaveExt() {
    oppId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    System.debug('opportunity Id: ' + oppId);
    opportunity = [SELECT Id, Name
                  FROM Opportunity
                  WHERE Id = :oppId];
}

public PageReference savePDF() {
    PageReference pdfPage = Page.QuoteOppProductVfp;
    pdfPage.getParameters().put('Id', oppId);
    pdfPage.setRedirect(true);
    PageReference ret = null;

    try {
        Blob pdfBlob = Test.isRunningTest()
                ? Blob.valueOf('Test PDF Content')
                : pdfPage.getContentAsPDF();

        ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion(
                Title = 'Quote ' + oppId,
                PathOnClient = 'Quote ' + oppId + '.pdf',
                VersionData = pdfBlob,
                FirstPublishLocationId = oppId
        );
        insert cv;
        System.debug('ContentVersion inserted: ' + cv);
        
        ret = new ApexPages.StandardController([SELECT Id FROM ContentDocument WHERE LatestPublishedVersionId = :cv.Id]).view();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ApexPages.addMessages(e);
        System.debug('An exception occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
    }
    System.debug('Returning PageReference: ' + ret);
    return ret;
    }
}
```

**The additional Visualforce page**

```
<apex:page controller="QuotePDFSaveExt" >
<apex:pageMessages />
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="preview and save">
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!savePDF}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:include pageName="QuoteOppProductVfp">
        </apex:include>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cut it into 2 pages, it'll be easier to maintain. I'll also use 2 separate apex controllers but it could be just one used in both.

First make your PDF. Simple, single concern, just make it pretty.

```apex
public with sharing class PdfPrint {
    // This can be done with pure Visualforce but just for demo sake
    Id accountId;
    public PdfPrint(ApexPages.StandardController ctrl) {
        accountId = ctrl.getId();
    }

    public List<Opportunity> getOpps(){
        return [SELECT Id, Name, StageName, CloseDate
        FROM Opportunity
        WHERE AccountId = :accountId
        ORDER BY Name];
    }
}
```

```xml
<!-- I called the page AccountAndOppsPdf -->
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="PdfPrint" readOnly="true" renderAs="pdf">
    <!-- put logo and stuff here, make this pretty -->
    <apex:detail subject="{!Account.Id}" relatedList="false" />
    <apex:pageBlock title="Opps">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!opps}" var="o">
            <apex:column value="{!o.Name}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!o.StageName}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!o.CloseDate}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Once you're happy with it - make the other page that displays 1st one in an iframe.

```apex
public with sharing class PdfPreview {
  Id accountId;
  public PdfPreview(ApexPages.StandardController ctrl) {
    accountId = ctrl.getId();
  }

  public Pagereference save() {
    PageReference pdfPage = Page.AccountAndOppsPdf;
    pdfPage.getParameters().put('Id', accountId);
    pdfPage.setRedirect(true);

    PageReference ret;

    try {
      Blob pdfBlob = Test.isRunningTest()
        ? Blob.valueOf('Test PDF Content')
        : pdfPage.getContentAsPDF();

      ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion(
        Title = 'Quote ' + accountId,
        PathOnClient = 'Quote ' + accountId + '.pdf',
        VersionData = pdfBlob,
        FirstPublishLocationId = accountId
      );
      insert cv;
      ret = new ApexPages.StandardController([SELECT Id FROM ContentDocument WHERE LatestPublishedVersionId = :cv.Id]).view();
    } catch (exception e) {
      ApexPages.addMessages(e);
    }
    return ret;
  }
}
```

```xml
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="PdfPreview">
    <apex:pageMessages />
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock title="preview and save">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:iframe src="{!URLFOR($Page.AccountAndOppsPdf, null, [id=Account.Id])}" scrolling="true" />
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Following what you provided, but maintaining my custom controller led to an "unknown constructor" error from my original VF page; then I attempted to use standard controller only (as you have provided), and got a null reference error.

Comment: your question doesn't contain any "unknown"? Update the question with fresh code samples (ideally remove unimportant bits like whole bodies of generateAndUploadPDF(), generateAndStoreQuoteNumber... null from which line? (if you run it with developer console open you should get a debug log). You can run with just a custom controller (no extensions) but then you need to read the record Id yourself from the page parameters... did you at least get the "pure" pdf to work? Is the problem "just" with the preview functionality?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply - I've made updated the code edits above. I did try to read the recordID from page parameters, which is not shown. Both the visibility of the PDF and the main controller work as I desire them to: the PDF shows the correct variables as I want it to look, and the main controller completes the main desired functionality (creating a unique quote number). The ability to save the PDF to files at the click of a button is the second desirable, to prevent the need to downloading then reupload the PDF to the opportunity.

Comment: `controller="QuoteOppProductCtrl" extensions="QuotePDFSaveExt"` - do you really need the extension in this page? Maybe `quoteoppproductctrl` is enough?
And I don't understand how that can be throwing a null but see if you can do `public QuotePDFSaveExt() {oppId = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id');}` and then in the outer page `<apex:page controller="QuotePDFSaveExt">...` and replace `id=Opportunity.Id` with `id=oppId`

Comment: Using your suggestion to not use extensions worked after a little bit more tinkering. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Post your own solution, I'd happily upvote that. And if you mark it accepted (you can accept your own answers) it'll drop off the list of unanswered ones and you'll get even more points ;)